# java applet buttons

Tags: java, swing, applet

OK so I have this applet thats like this

- BorderLayout.CENTER - (Within this is JPanel)
- BorderLayout.EAST - (Within this is a new GridLayout (4,5)
- BorderLayout.SOUTH - (Within this is a TextArea)

Anyway, on the applet, I have to HOVER over the buttons to see them. They don't paint there I guess but I'm adding them in the init() method... so I don't know what I am doing wrong and why it's doing this.

```
setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
JPanel invOne = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5,4));
JPanel game = new JPanel();
add(invOne, BorderLayout.EAST);
add(game, BorderLayout.CENTER);
add(c, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

invOne.setBounds(416,0, 60, 28);

for (int i = 0,  j = 20;  i < 20;  i = i+1, j = j-1)  {
   invOne.add(new JButton("SLOT " + j));
   invOne.setBounds(32,32,100,100);
   invOne.setFocusable(false);
}

game.setBounds(0,0, 416, 288);
repaint();
```

Comment: Yet again you post random bits of code that don't help us solve the problem. You have been asked for a SSCCE in the past. Learn how to create on and post it so we don't waste time guessing what silly mistake you are doing this time. There are plenting of examples in the Swing tutorial. Download them and test them and learm to post a proper question. Yes the tutorial even has an simple JApplet example.

Comment: See a few posts of mine, I added the SSCCE.

Comment: PS -Technically I did post a proper question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to accomplish with all the `setBounds()` calls? Either you let `pack()` set your panel's size according to what's inside, or you set bounds *once* to where you want to see that panel sit. Especially the calls with a size of 32x32 pixels are not helping at all.

---

EDIT:

I found these problems:

- As one other poster mentioned, you're mixing Swing and AWT components. That doesn't work well. Essentially, if some of the components you use have a "J" at the beginning, you'll want to go with "J"'s for all of them. AWT is now considered "old school". It's a bit confusing because some classes and components used in GUIs don't have J's. I guess you need to work carefully with good examples or look the classes up.
- For some reason, the applet didn't want to work well until I gave explicit row/column counts to the TextArea (now called JTextArea). I changed `new TextArea()` to `new JTextArea(3,20)`.
- The biggest problem may have been the empty `paint()` method. I wonder how the applet displayed anything at all? You could have removed the `paint()` method; I fixed it by calling `super.paint()`.
- Finally, class names (such as `bl`) should start with uppercase characters. The compiler in IdeOne grumbled at me for that.

[Here's my fixed code](http://ideone.com/MdvYz).

Happy hacking!

Comment: OK here is code itSELF... http://www.dasdas.pastebin.com/ftwpx7rK It just has the GUI... and when I tried compiling I get: 

C:\Documents and Settings\djasnowski\My Documents\bl.java:33: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method pack()
location: class bl
  this.pack();

Comment: I hope to have it fixed soon. I'll report back.

Comment: I got it. I changed Applet to JApple but now the grey jPanel is overlapping the drawn tiles (drawImage) tiles...

Comment: Updated my post. Read my comments carefully.

Comment: Great! But my image is still being overlapped by a JPanel. I assume JPanel over laps image for whatever reason I do not know about :S

Comment: Is the component you're showing the image in large enough to show the whole image?

Comment: I think so. It's a 32x32 image and the JPanel it's in is 12x8 of 32x32 sqaure tiles.

Comment: Hmm. Sorry, I'll have to go soon. So: You know the drill, please post a new question on SO with "why are my images being overlaid?", post your complete code and with luck someone will be along to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Found [one page (in german language)](http://www.wer-weiss-was.de/theme35/article3597967.html) which describes the same problem: JButton widgets only show up after hovering over them.

The problem there was that AWT and Swing components/widgets have been mixed. I can't see from your code fragment if this is the case, but if you have `java.awt.*` imports, disable them, refactor your code to only use Swing classes and try again / hope for the best.

Another suggestion was to explicitely do a `setVisible(true)` for every button, but the questioner said, that this didn't help in his case.

Answer (score 1):

After adding all your components in the panel, do you explicitely call the "pack()" (or the "repaint()") method ?
Not calling theses methods can result in graphic troubles in your Frames...

Comment: OK, I added the code. As you can see I added repaint() but to no luck... (By the way, it's an applet not a Frame)

Answer (score 1):

You are using Swing components in an Applet. You should use JApplet. Just change `extends Applet` to `extends JApplet`.